# Thymeleaf, Spring MVC, web-app and rest modules. cant handle map<Fuel> in localhost:8081/transpors endpoint

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, model-view-controller

Hello my application is separated in 2 parts that have data exchange in json format web-app <-> service-rest
I have problem when try to use localhost:8081/transports endpoint. That should give me transports template with data.
Instead i got error:

```
 class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.epam.brest.courses.model.Fuel (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.epam.brest.courses.model.Fuel is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @6ddbbfbb)
at com.epam.brest.courses.web_app.TransportController.getFuelsMap (TransportController.java:198)
```

I searh that promblem and find that jackson dont know how to serialize or deserialize Map in this part:[github web-app transport controller](https://github.com/Brest-Java-Course-2020/aignathick-fuel-accounting/blob/4edb3d684d1f06f94e435e162a9bc80b38ea30f7/fuel-accounting-web-app/src/main/java/com/epam/brest/courses/web_app/TransportController.java#L55)

i use this map to get fuel by id, in thymeleaf templete: [github thymeleaf template get fuel by id from map](https://github.com/Brest-Java-Course-2020/aignathick-fuel-accounting/blob/4edb3d684d1f06f94e435e162a9bc80b38ea30f7/fuel-accounting-web-app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/transports.html#L115)

there are links for [rest-app transportController](https://github.com/Brest-Java-Course-2020/aignathick-fuel-accounting/blob/4edb3d684d1f06f94e435e162a9bc80b38ea30f7/fuel-accounting-rest-app/src/main/java/com/epam/brest/courses/rest_app/TransportController.java#L34) and [web-app transportController](https://github.com/Brest-Java-Course-2020/aignathick-fuel-accounting/blob/4edb3d684d1f06f94e435e162a9bc80b38ea30f7/fuel-accounting-web-app/src/main/java/com/epam/brest/courses/web_app/TransportController.java#L52)

can you please help how to write code, to get off this problem with map.

p.s. endpoing localhost:8081/fuels work fine, because i dont use any map there.

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<Fuel> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Fuel>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Fuel>>() {};
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseType);
        return (List<Fuel>) responseEntity.getBody();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your FuelService.

```
@Override
public List<Fuel> findAll() {
    LOGGER.debug("findAll()");
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, List.class);
    return (List<Fuel>) responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Do not use getForEntity(url, List.class), the list is not typesafe.
try instead:

```
template.exchange(url, GET, new HttpEntity<>(), newParameterizedTypeReference<List<Fuel>>() { });
```

This will return a typesafe ResponseEntity, which should be able to be to work.

Comment: ty for your help!